# Windows: start/stop (toggle) portable XAMPP via single batch file. Switch between multiple XAMPPs

Tags: windows, batch-file, process, xampp, toggle

I have multiple portable XAMPP Servers on my local **windows** machine (to simulate each production Server I work on).

In order to start one of the local XAMPP Servers, I have to make sure no other XAMPP is running, otherwise it won't start. So I have to find the correct **xampp_stop.exe** each time I want to switch servers and get the correct **xampp_start.exe** for the one I want to switch to.

I think an ideal setup would look like this:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Shortcuts\

    |__"xammp serverName1 toggle.bat"
    |__"xammp serverName2 toggle.bat"
    |__"xammp serverName3 toggle.bat"
    |__"xammp kill.bat"
    ...
```

The **toggle** batch files would kill any previous running server and start the one respectively.

The **kill** batch file would kill any running server.

All placed inside the **Shortcuts** directory to have fast excess via WindowsKey+Search.

Does anyone know an approach on this?

Comment: What is the logic for identifying which server to stop?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. It works well with all XAMPP Servers I have installed.

This script shuts down any server before it starts the one it belongs to.
The script just uses the existing apache/mysql start/stop batch files which are located inside XAMPP root.
In order to call the batches hidden (without any permanent console window) they are called by a virtual basic script. Here is how that works: https://superuser.com/a/62646/431390
It is quite simple.

And this is the Batch to start the server it belongs to. It goes into each XAMPP root.

XAMPP_root/**XAMPP_Start.bat**

```
@echo off

wscript.exe "C:\someDir\invisible.vbs" %~dp0"apache_stop.bat"
wscript.exe "C:\someDir\invisible.vbs" %~dp0"mysql_stop.bat"

wscript.exe "C:\someDir\invisible.vbs" %~dp0"apache_start.bat"
wscript.exe "C:\someDir\invisible.vbs" %~dp0"mysql_start.bat"

exit
```

The next file is the batch file to shut down any XAMPP server. It's just the first part of the other one...

XAMPP_root/**XAMPP_Stop.bat**

```
@echo off

wscript.exe "C:\someDir\invisible.vbs" %~dp0"apache_stop.bat"
wscript.exe "C:\someDir\invisible.vbs" %~dp0"mysql_stop.bat"

exit
```

The next file is the vbs script, that starts the batch files hidden. So that the whole thing won't occupy any console windows.

C:/someDir/**invisible.vbs***

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```